# App from Mac App Store. What if I change Macs?

Tags: mac-appstore

The Mac App Store is really convenient, but under some circumstances, I am confused on how it manages the installation. Here I have two questions:

1. If I buy an app from the Mac App Store, then delete it, can I re-install it or do I have to buy it again?
2. If I buy an app from the Mac App Store, can I install it on more than one Mac? If I can't, can I delete it on the Mac that I purchased the app from, and then install it on another Mac?

Answer (score 6):

There is no limit on installing one copy of each app on every Mac you own or control for personal use.

You only pay once and can re-download the app even if the developer changes prices later.

Comment: How to do that? Just go to the other Mac, launch mac app store, login with the Apple ID, and just download and install? Just like that?

Comment: Yes. Once you log in, you can browse to your past purchases and click all the apps you need. Just install, no more buying.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-download the app for free (using the same Apple ID that you used to originally purchase it) **as long as the developer hasn't taken the app off-sale**.

Also you can simply copy the app's package from the old mac into the new one (Time Machine migration is one easy alternative). On the app's first launch, the App Store will ask you to login with the Apple ID that was used to originally purchase the app. Just enter your Apple ID and password and then the app will run normally.